# Multiple, but unique, class inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, virtual-functions

The problem is: `ExampleIt` which inherits (and overrides methods) from class `It`, so that when I overload operator in class `Wrapped` (which calls some methods from `It`, which should be overridden by `ExampleIt`.

The wanted effect is that when I overload `operator*` I should be able to call `*name_of_Wrapped_class` and this should execute virtual method `dereference` (from `It`) which should be overridden by `ExampleIt`.

```
class It {
public:
    virtual std::pair<int, std::string> dereference() const;
};

class ExampleIt : It {
public:
    std::pair<int, std::string> dereference() const override;
};

class Wrapped : It{ //??? not sure about that
public:
     std::pair<int, std::string> operator*() const; // it should call for dereference()
};
```

Comment: Does your object derive from both `Wrapped` *and* `ExampleIt`? Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking. Perhaps you meant to make `Wrapped` inherit from `ExampleIt`?

Comment: Do you mean that `Wrapped` should hold a pointer or reference to `It` which could refer to any class derived from `It`.?

Comment: Are just trying to create a shim helper function that calls on the virtual function? You can just declare such functions in your interface base class.

Comment: There is no relationship between `Wrapped` and `ExampleIt`  (other than they happen to both derive from `It`).     Member functions of either are not member functions of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Before actually answering, I have to say your class hierarchy and naming seem kind of fishy. Your dereferencing operator returns a value rather than a reference - which is not how dereferencing works on plain pointers.

Still, you asked for it, so here you go. Two options to implement your `operator*()` overloading (each with its pros and cons which I won't go into here):

1. Run-time polymorphic behavior, using a pointer:

   ```
   class Wrapped {
   protected:
       It* it;
   public:
       std::pair<int, std::string> operator*() const {
           return it->dereference();
       };
   };
   ```
2. Compile-time polymorphism using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp):

   ```
   template <typename Base>
   class Wrapped: Base {
   public:
       std::pair<int, std::string> operator*() const {
           return Base::dereference();
       };
   };
   ```

   with this option, you don't even need `It` and `ExampleIt` to be related; any class with a `dereference()` method will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code, which I think shows what you want,

```
      #include <iostream>

      using namespace std;

      class It {
      public:
          virtual std::pair<int, std::string> dereference() const{
              std::cout << "it\n";
              return make_pair(3, "");
          }
      };

      class ExampleIt : public It {
      public:
        std::pair<int, std::string> dereference() const override{
              std::cout << "example it\n";
              return make_pair(2, "");
          }
      };

      class Wrapped {
          It * it;
      public:
          Wrapped() : it (new ExampleIt()) {}
           std::pair<int, std::string> operator*() const{
              std::cout << "Wrapped it\n";
              it->dereference();
              return make_pair(1, "");
           }
      };

      int main() {
          Wrapped p;
          auto x = *p;
          std::cout << x.first << std::endl;
      }
```

Note the member `it` was assigned during the construction with type ExampleIt.